# error C2039 : 'sort': is not a member of 'std' even though I have already included algorithm header

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, std

I am experiencing an error while writing a C++ DLL in Visual Studio 2019. I have already included algorithm and cstdlib headers.

here is my code for reference :

```
#include "TestDLLSort.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include "pch.h"
#include <cstdlib>

extern "C" {
    void TestSort(int a[], int length) {
        std::sort(a, a + length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `pch.h` is the 'stop' file for your precompiled header, then that should be the first `#include`. Strange things can happen if it's not.

Comment: Agree with @AdrianMole. Most likelly it is precompiled headers. Other code works https://onlinegdb.com/rymf7qVtI